# Is there any python code for applying a-law/mu-law on 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, continuous-signals, numpy, dynamic-range-compression, companding

I have 3D numpy array of probabilities between [0,1], I need to emphasize on some area with lower probabilities. I was suggested to apply a-law and mu-law.

I am wondering if there is python library/code that I can use for this purpose. I would really appreciate if you share some ideas here. Thanks

Comment: The formula is on wikipedia, it is quite simple. Should take minutes to write a function to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do that